# Why is in-app purchase prices on Itunes Connect unusual? $1.23, $2.46 etc

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I literally just uploaded another app and selected an in-app purchase price of 2.99 but with this new app the options are all weird. What is going on?

[image]

Comment: What region/country are you setting prices for?

Comment: I think it depends on the country you're setting the prices for, as the exchange rate changes for each currency.

Comment: Well I am in the USA (cali). I submitted another app and the options were x.99, so now I am a bit confused.

Comment: It looks like you were looking at prices for Iceland.